# Where is the registry key for the metro wallpaper in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, registry, wallpaper, regedit

Where is the key in Windows 8 so you can change the metro wallpaper (the one on the start menu) so I can have something else than the default ones. I know there are programs out there that can do this but I need the key so I can use it in a program of my own.

I know the normal dekstop wallpaper location is in the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Dekstop\Wallpaper
```

Comment: Protip: first look for an API to change settings, *then*, if nothing comes up, consider looking for a registry key. Changing directly the registry is almost never supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unsupported.  If you try to get this behaviour into an app (I assume you are asking so you can code it, otherwise your question would be on superuser) then you will fail certification and your app won't make it to the store.